# How to generate a URL containing variables from an object

Tags: url

I'm attempting to pass data from salesforce into an external application. The external app can absorb url variables but I'm failing to understand how I would dynamically append values from a SF object to an endpoint at the external app.

For example pulling from the opportunity object:

[https://app.external.com/s/12345?acctID={!Opportunity.AccountId}&contID={!Opportunity.ContractId}](https://app.external.com/s/12345?acctID=%7B!Opportunity.AccountId%7D&contID=%7B!Opportunity.ContractId%7D)

Is there a module I could use to set that base url then generate the appending values after the '?'

Is this only possible using the APEX API?

Comment: How/when do you want this data to get there? I can think of probably close to a dozen ways you can get it there, depending on what you need.

Comment: Assuming you talking about call that external api from Apex, you can soql query object details and set them as http query params in the url you are trying to send.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

My client wants to set a trigger to send out a link when a case or opportunity closes and would like to append some variables to the url. I'm at a loss how to help them set up that trigger.